# pygame.Sound.get_num_channels not accurate

Tags: python, audio, sdl, pygame, twisted

I'm using pygame + Twisted. I made a `Sound` wrapper class, the relevant parts of which are here:

```
class Sound(object):
    def __init__(self, sound):
        self.sound = sound

        self._status_task = task.LoopingCall(self._check_status)
        self._status_task.start(0.05)

    def _check_status(self):
        chans = self.sound.get_num_channels()
        if chans > 0:
            logger.debug("'%s' playing on %d channels",
                         self.filename, chans)

    def play(self):
        self.sound.play()
```

What happens, though, is that well after a sound is done playing, `.get_num_channels()` is returning a positive number, e.g.:

```
2013-07-08 15:13:30,502-DEBUG-engine.sound - 'sounds/foo.wav' playing on 2 channels
2013-07-08 15:13:30,503-DEBUG-engine.sound - 'sounds/bar.wav' playing on 1 channels
2013-07-08 15:13:30,546-DEBUG-engine.sound - 'sounds/foo.wav' playing on 2 channels
2013-07-08 15:13:30,558-DEBUG-engine.sound - 'sounds/bar.wav' playing on 1 channels
2013-07-08 15:13:30,602-DEBUG-engine.sound - 'sounds/foo.wav' playing on 2 channels
```

Why is this the case?

I ask because sometimes the sound doesn't play at all when I tell it to and I'm trying to get to the bottom of that. I figure understanding this might help with that bug.

Comment: for the curious: the reason sound wasn't playing was because i had 2 pygame programs running, and only the currently focused one emits sounds. that seems unrelated to this bug, however

Comment: I wonder if this is because the sample length is *close* to the loop interval, and sometimes it hasn't quite finished playing by the time the loop begins playing it again?  Oh, or if the output is realistic, then it seems it is `foo.wav` that is always on two channels.  Maybe `foo.wav` is slightly longer than the loop interval but `bar.wav` is sufficiently shorter?

Comment: Can you post your whole code? My best guess is that the pygame internal event queue which keeps sound playing isn't being updated properly. See [pygame.event.pump](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump).

Comment: does the sound have lots of nothing at the end?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience get_num_channels() counts all the channels that have the sound assigned to them, even if they have finished playing.

A solution would be to go and check whether these channels are still "busy".
You can change your _check_status method to this, to take into account if the channels are active:

```
def _check_status(self):
    chans = self.sound.get_num_channels()
    if chans > 0:
        logger.debug("'%s' assigned to %d channels", self.filename, chans)              
        active_chans = 0
        for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
            channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
            if channel.get_sound() == self.sound and channel.get_busy():
                active_chans += 1
        logger.debug("'%s' actively playing on %d channels", self.filename, active_chans)
```

And two helper functions that could be helpful for anybody else experiencing this issue:

```
def get_num_active_channels(sound):
    """
    Returns the number of pygame.mixer.Channel that are actively playing the sound.
    """
    active_channels = 0
    if sound.get_num_channels() > 0:
        for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
            channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
            if channel.get_sound() == sound and channel.get_busy():
                active_channels += 1
    return active_channels

def get_active_channel(sound):
    """
    Returns the first pygame.mixer.Channel that we find that is actively playing the sound.
    """
    if sound.get_num_channels() > 0:
        for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
            channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
            if channel.get_sound() == sound and channel.get_busy()
                return channel
    return None
```